# File is not required option using multer (MEAN stack)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, multer

I run into a problem creating my first RESTapi app.

I have a multer module included to get a file uploaded using form and everything works great until I provide the file.

If the file is not provided then my app crashes, so if someone will trigger a post route in my API to create a new entity(using curl for example) the app will crash.

It seems like file is always required when using multer to upload it.

My router.post looks like this:

```
router.post('/movies', upload.single('image'), function(req, res, next) {
var movie = new Movie(req.body);
movie.fileName = req.file.filename;
movie.save(function(err, movie){
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.json(movie);
}); });
```

So the question is:

Is it possible to leave the "file" field empty and still process saving data to db simply without fileName field? Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you upload your schema code.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that multer requires a file - you just need to guard against req.file being undefined. You're referencing `req.file.filename` without checking whether req.file exists. Simply check whether it exists and if so set the filename on the movie:

```
router.post('/movies', upload.single('image'), function(req, res, next) {
  var movie = new Movie(req.body);
  if(req.file) movie.fileName = req.file.filename;
  movie.save(function(err, movie){
      if(err) return next(err);
      res.json(movie);
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes I already did exactly as you said. It was so simple though. I think when I asked this question, my problem was a lack of sleep :D But thank You anyways I'll mark your answer as a correct one